# How to call IEnumerator with parameter in c# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUXtr.png)

I am using UnityWebRequest to fill my form by using unity WebRequest i want to call function in my button so i  am using Ienumerator because void is not iterative .

Comment: Simply pass all the parameters where you call the method, there shouldn't be any problem

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Just put the required parameters in the parenthesis of `LoginApi` inside `StartCoroutine` call

```
public void Login(string email, string password, string loginType
{
    StartCoroutine(LoginApi(email, password, loginType));
}
```